# how to call a path from .ini file into bat command string?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a .ini file called job1.ini and this .ini contains information which I need to work with by injecting it on a specific spot in my batch script.

batch script is in the same folder as my .ini file

content of job1.ini:

> [JobSet]
>
> Codec=hevc
>
> Video=**E:\folder\B 1.265**
>
> VideoWidth=1920
>
> VideoHeight=1080

my script:

> "C:\Temp\mkvmerge.exe" -o "E:\done.mkv" --title "B 1" "**here_I_need_that_path_from_ini**" "C:\Temp\audio.flac"

also I found this:

> for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr Video job1.ini') do set
> Video=%%a

how could I combine these 3 pieces, so my script would work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr Video job1.ini') do set Video=%%a
```

can't work because findstr will also match the `Videoheight/VideoWidth` entries and have the resulting environment variable `Video=1080`

Try this (untested):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Video="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i "^Video=" job1.ini') do set "%%a"
if defined Video "C:\Temp\mkvmerge.exe" -o "E:\done.mkv" --title "B 1" "%Video%" "C:\Temp\audio.flac"
```